# .NET Core 2.0 Docker image missing and backwards compatibility

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

2 Days ago my 2.0 .net Core project stopped building the Docker image. I can't find any news about that so i'm guessing it's because the version is out of support from a long time ago, so they just removed it?

Also i am finding mixed responses about backwards compatibility. Is a .net 2.1 docker image compatible with a 2.0 project?

I am receiving the following error:

```
[1/4] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:2.0
resolve mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:2.0 0.1s done
ERROR: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:2.0 not found
[internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:2.0:
 [1/4] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:2.0:
 failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: failed to load cache key: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:2.0 not found
```

Comment: 2.1 and 2.0 both starts with major 2, so why not compatible? by the way, i believe you can find aspnet:2.0 base image elsewhere, e.g. from some mirror registries, or even locally? next time you'd better bak up the base image...

Comment: If i use the  2.1 image, i get the following error.  
 An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (Account.Api.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore', version: '2.1.1'
    path: 'lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.dll'
  This assembly was expected to be in the local runtime store as the application was published using the following target manifest files:
    aspnetcore-store-2.0.0-linux-x64.xml;aspnetcore-store-2.0.0-osx-x64.xml;aspnetcore-store-2.0.0-win7-x64.xml;aspnetcore-store-2.0.0-win7-x86.xml

Comment: I think you can try to build dotnet images by yourself based on https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker

Comment: Do you know a guide or something to do that? I have no idea how to do it lol

Comment: is it a lot of effort to upgrade source code to later versions?

Comment: Well i wasn't sure, but i upgraded it yesterday and it was easier than i tought to 2.1. Now i'm trying to find out if theres chance for runtime errors

Comment: take a chance to 3.x or even 5.0 is even better